# 2 question about power rules from a test i had today

Tags: calculus

Well, i had a test today morning and i didn't succeed to answer these 2 question, so i hope you can answer me and help me understand, tnx!

1)consider  $0<x\in \mathbb{R}$ , $x^{\frac{5}{7}}<x^{\frac{8}{11}}$, what we can say about x?
2) prove that $sup\left\{x\in Q:\:5^x+2\cdot 3^x\le 43\right\}\:\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: For #$1$, because $8/11 \gt5/7$, we know that $x \gt 1$.

Comment: @Bye_World thats obvious, but how to prove this is the question

Comment: First show that for $a\gt 0$, we have $x^a\gt 1$ iff $x\gt 1$.  Then you can prove that it's monotone increasing by noticing that for $m\gt n$, $a^m=a^{n}a^{m-n}\gt a^n$.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: note that $\frac{5}{7}=\frac{55}{77}$ and that $\frac{8}{11}=\frac{56}{77}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**
1. If $0<x<1$ and $a<b$ then $x^a>x^b$. If $x>1$ and $a<b$ then $x^a<x^b$ (do you see why?)
2. The function $f(x)=5^x+2\cdot 3^x$ is monotonous (i.e. if $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$) and $f(2)=43$.